# If $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = 1$, what is the the minimum value of $\frac {ab}{c} + \frac {bc}{a} + \frac {ca}{b}$?

Tags: inequality, optimization, symmetric-polynomials, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, rearrangement-inequality

> Suppose that $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = 1$ for real positive numbers $a$, $b$, $c$. Find the minimum possible value of $\frac {ab}{c} + \frac {bc}{a} + \frac {ca}{b}$.

So far I've got a minimum of $\sqrt {3}$. Can anyone confirm this? However, I've been having trouble actually proofing that this is the lower bound. Typically, I've solved problems where I need to prove an inequality as true, but this problem is a bit different asking for the minimum of an inequality instead, and I'm not sure how to show that $\sqrt {3}$ is the lower bound of it. Any ideas?

Comment: This is basically $(x+y+z)^2\geq 3(xy+yz+zx)$ inequality in disguise. Try to find the right substitution.

Comment: To show that $\sqrt{3}$ is the minimum value, suppose that there exits some real $y_0$ such that $y_0 < \sqrt{3}$ and $y_0$ is possible value of the expression you are considering. Then derive a contradiction

Comment: Is it allowed to use Lagrange's Multipliers?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Trivially, we have $(x-y)^2 + (y-z)^2 + (z-x)^2 \geq 0$, so we get
$$(x+y+z)^2 \geq 3(xy+yz+xz)$$
by adding to both sides of the equation. Thus by plugging in $x = \frac{ab}{c}$, $y = \frac{bc}{a}$, $z = \frac{ca}{b}$, we get
$$\left(\frac{ab}{c} + \frac{bc}{a} + \frac{ca}{b}\right)^2 \geq 3(b^2 + c^2 + a^2) = 3$$
and thus $\frac{ab}{c} + \frac{bc}{a} + \frac{ca}{b} \geq\sqrt{3}$.
We attain equality by setting $a=b=c=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$.

Answer (score 3):

We have
$$\left(\frac {ab}{c} + \frac {bc}{a} + \frac {ca}{b}\right)^2 = \frac {a^2b^2}{c^2} + \frac {b^2c^2}{a^2} + \frac {c^2a^2}{b^2}+2(a^2+b^2+c^2).$$
Using the AM-GM inequality, we get
$$\frac {a^2b^2}{c^2} + \frac {b^2c^2}{a^2} + \frac {c^2a^2}{b^2} = \frac{1}{2} \sum \left(\frac {a^2b^2}{c^2} + \frac {b^2c^2}{a^2}\right) \geqslant \sum \sqrt{\frac {a^2b^2}{c^2} \cdot  \frac {b^2c^2}{a^2}}=a^2+b^2+c^2.$$
Therefore
$$\left(\frac {ab}{c} + \frac {bc}{a} + \frac {ca}{b}\right)^2 \geqslant 3(a^2+b^2+c^2) = 3,$$
or
$$\frac {ab}{c} + \frac {bc}{a} + \frac {ca}{b} \geqslant \sqrt 3.$$
Equality occur when $a=b=c=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}.$

Answer (score 2):

For $a=b=c=\frac{1}{\sqrt3}$ we obtain a value $\sqrt3$.

We'll prove that it's a minimal value.

Indeed, we need to prove that:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{ab}{c}\geq\sqrt{3(a^2+b^2+c^2)}$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}a^2b^2\geq\sqrt{3a^2b^2c^2(a^2+b^2+c^2)}$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(a^4b^4-a^4b^2c^2)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}c^4(a^2-b^2)^2\geq0$$ and we are done!

Answer (score 0):

I found a stronger version: $$\frac{ab}{c}+\frac{bc}{a}+\frac{ca}{b}\ge \sqrt{4(a^2+b^2+c^2)-ab-bc-ca}$$ is true $\forall a,b,c>0$

Note: It's just Schur 3 degree