# Find the min value of $\frac{xy}{z}+\frac{xz}{y}+\frac{yz}{x}$ when ${x^2} + {y^2} + {z^2} = 1$.

Tags: inequality, contest-math, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

I don't have problems usually with these types of inequalities. They usually have a simple trick where you either take them two by two or else to get the question. Or factor out $x + y + z$ etc.

However when I tried to solve this it became kinda challenging.

I proved through *AM-GM* that :
$$\frac{xy}{z} + \frac{yz}{x} + \frac{xz}{y} ≥ x + y + z $$

But this doesn't really help , as the condition is with ${x^2} + {y^2} + {z^2} = 1$.

I tried some other methods , but I failed. Any help is welcomed.

Comment: Is there any additional condition, like $x$, $y$ and $z$ must be positive or something like that? Otherwise, it could easily be shown that there is no minimum: Let $x=-\frac{3}{5}$, $y=\frac{4}{5}-t$ and $z=\sqrt{t(\frac{8}{5}-t)}$ and now take a look at $t\to 0_{+}$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = 1$, what is the the minimum value of $\frac {ab}{c} + \frac {bc}{a} + \frac {ca}{b}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3777113/if-a2-b2-c2-1-what-is-the-the-minimum-value-of-frac-abc-fra) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cfrac%7Bxy%7D%7Bz%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7Bxz%7D%7By%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7Byz%7D%7Bx%7D%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24%7Bx%5E2%7D%2B%7By%5E2%7D%2B%7Bz%5E2%7D%3D1%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Aminimum&p=1). Note another duplicate is on this site is ...

Comment: (cont.) [minimum value of $\frac{xy}{z}+\frac{yz}{x}+\frac{xz}{y}$ if $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$](/q/3880366). There are also several AoPS threads, e.g., [An inequality](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1455082p8369003) (which says the source is "All Russian $1988$ Grade $10$ number $2$"), [inequality](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3h2587671p22295759), etc. Last, but not least, welcome to Math SE.

Answer (score 3):

We observe that, if $x,y,z>0$ does not hold, then the global minimum does not exist . Therefore, we need the restriction $x,y,z>0$ .

---

Let $\thinspace\dfrac {xy}{z}=a,\thinspace \dfrac {xz}{y}=b,\thinspace \dfrac {yz}{x}=c$ . Then, the *original* problem is equivalent to :

$$\min \{a+b+c\}=X$$

where $ab+bc+ac=1$ and $a,b,c>0$ .

---

Since

$$
\begin{align}(a+b+c)^2&≥3(ab+bc+ac)=3\end{align}\tag 1
$$

We conclude that :

$$
\begin{align}|a+b+c|=a+b+c≥\sqrt 3\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace\tiny{\blacksquare}\end{align}
$$

Indeed, since we need the condition $a+b+c>0$ here, this forces the condition $x,y,z>0$ to be satisfied .

---

$(1)\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace $  Note that, the inequality

$$
\small {\begin{align}\frac {(a-b)^2}{2}+\frac {(b-c)^2}{2}+\frac {(c-a)^2}{2}≥0\end{align}}
$$

leads to :

$$a^2+b^2+c^2≥ab+bc+ac$$

which is equivalent to :

$$(a+b+c)^2≥3(ab+bc+ac)\thinspace .$$

Comment: Where did you get the $(a+b+c)^2\geq 3(ab+bc+ac)$ from? Is it some well known theorem or follows immediately from one? Or do we have to use the principle axis theorem and show $(a+b+c)^2 = 3(ab+bc+ac)+\frac{1}{4}(a-2b+c)^2+\frac{3}{4}(a-c)^2$?

Comment: @ReinhardMeier Please, give me some time and I will expand the answer. Thank you for your feedback .

Comment: @ReinhardMeier I expanded the answer as much as I could .

Comment: Yes. Nice solution. Would it make sense to mention that the minimum is attained for $$
x=y=z=a=b=c=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\,?
$$ I only see lots of $\ge$ signs. :)

Comment: @KurtG. This would definitely be better.  Let me add.  Thank you for your feedback .